# If a function $f$ is measurable in the completion space then there is a function $g$ measurable in the original space, $f$ = $g$ a.e

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have a question about this proof of a theorem from Yeh’s Real Analysis (3rd edition).

The theorem and proof are in the attached images:

[image: Part 1]

[image: Part 2]

My question pertains to the part that says:

$\{D : g < r_n\} = \{D \setminus N : g < r_n\} \cup \{N : g < r_n\}$

How do we get that $D \setminus N \cup N = D$? This is only true if $N \subseteq D$, but I’m not sure exactly how this came to be. I’m guessing it’s from the fact that D is a complete measure space? But it’s a bit vague to me.

Thanks!

Comment: What is $D$ to begin with? And why it is not $X$?

Comment: @WillM. I don’t think I understand your question. $D$ is defined in the statement of the theorem. It could be $X$, I suppose? But why would it necessarily be?

Comment: So, the author is actually assuming the measure space to be $(D, \mathfrak{A})$?

Comment: @WillM. No, $\mathfrak{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$ and $D \in \mathfrak{A}$ so $D \subseteq X$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the author is just taking the measure space $(D, \mathfrak{A}_D)$ where $\mathfrak{A}_D$ is the _trace_ of the sigma algebra on $D$ (that is, the measurable sets contained in $D$). So you can assume $X = D.$

Comment: @JaneDoe I see from your profile that you have not accepted answers to many of the questions you have asked. If any particular answer has helped you resolve the question, then consider upvoting and accepting an answer. This is considered good practice on this site, and helps remove your question from the unanswered list.

Comment: @Brahadeesh accepted your answer, thanks. (I have accepted answers for most of the questions I have received a satisfactory answer to. I will double check if any are missing.)

Comment: @JaneDoe sure, thanks for responding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question pertains to equation $(1)$, observe that the same assumption, namely that $D = (D \setminus N) \cup N$, is made earlier when defining $g$ on $D$ by defining it separately on $D \setminus N$ and $N$.

You are right that the author is assuming that $N \subset D$, and that this is not true from the way $N$ is defined. However, if we let $N' := N \cap D$, then the same proof goes through with $N'$ in place of $N$. For instance, it is clear that $N' \in \mathfrak{A}$, $N' \subset D$, $N'$ is a null set and $C_n \subset B_n \subset N'$. Note that you are not using the fact that $D$ is a complete measure space, you only need that $D, N \in \mathfrak{A}$ to conclude that $D \cap N \in \mathfrak{A}$, etc.

So, we can take without loss of generality that $N$ is a subset of $D$. But the author should have mentioned this for the sake of clarity, in my opinion. Good catch.